# react native background blur without npm packages

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i am using animated ScrollView and Modal. and i need this blurry background on modal shown on right pic.
how can i add this background to this modal? i want blurry effect without npm packages.

```
<Modal transparent={true}>
```

[image: 2]
[image: 1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground

and use the component prop **blurRadius** like:

```js
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const image = { uri: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png" };

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground source={image} blurRadius={5} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Inside</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 42,
    lineHeight: 84,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#000000c0"
  }
});

export default App;
```